# Getting bitmap size in pixels on screen, not the actual size?

Tags: android, graphics

I have a layout that has some horizontal scroll on top, some text box on the bottom and whatever space is left in the middle I fill it with an ImageView. In that ImageView I load a bitmap. Let's call this ImageView the **bottom one**.

Now, on top of that ImageView I load dynamically another ImageView that the user can move about by dragging it. The second ImageView (**top one**) has a small icon in it that will be overlayed on top of my bitmap and saved. Think of it as a logo/watermark.

Both ImageViews are in a RelativeLayout, so I can move the top layout around.

Now the problem I have is that I can not get the size of the bitmap that is loaded in the **bottom** ImageView.

I have tried the following:

```
DisplayMetrics om = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(om);
tv.setText("W:" + b.getScaledWidth(om) + " H:" + b.getScaledHeight(om));
```

but it won't work, ***b.getScaledWidth(om)*** returns the actual width of my bitmap and not the one on screen, which should be (in case of a landscape image) 480px, the size of the screen of the phone I am testing on.

ADDITIONAL INFO: Why I need this is because the image I show in bottom ImageView is not of the same proportions as the ImageView. So I can get the size of the ImageView but this ImageView is larger then the image itself. As I need to keep the top ImageView inside the boundaries of image that is shown in bottom ImageView I need to know the size of the image in the bottom ImageView and not the size of the bottom View itself.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way so I did it "manually".

I extended *ImageView* class with my *MyImageView* class and in the *onMeasure* override I have calculated scale factor and accordingly created a *Rect* representing boundaries in coordinates according to my *RelativeLayout*, inside of which is *MyImageView*.

I went this way because I found a post here that referred to creating own *ImageView* class, can't find a link anymore.

Anyway, after that I check top/left positioning of **top** *ImageView* and set the maximum location while moving it around in the *onTouch* method.